# Postpone an sql transaction

Tags: php, mariadb

I would like to trigger an SQL transaction (database query) after a specific time (e.g. 5 days) from an event (e.g. a user clicked a button) in my website running on php server.

Comment: ok. thats nice.

Comment: But where will the query's output go?

Answer (score 1):

You need a cronjob that checks for pending tasks on a table where you store the event setting a datetime that states when it has to be executed.